# Synonym for "dynamically driven"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking to replace the phrase "dynamically driven". Bit of context from where is from/going: I'm describing a bit of tech that is essentially inert, it's not pre-recorded, but at [runtime](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dynamic) uses that data to generate output.

Comment: What's wrong with dynamically driven?

Comment: Absolutely nothing whatsoever. But I was using the word "dynamic" a lot in the same paragraph, hence the need for a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

"autoloaded"

"activated on demand"

Answer (score 1):

You can also say “database driven” or “dynamic application.”

Keep in mind that these are terms of art in computer programming. You don’t necessarily want to get creative with them.